# How does one populate datatables from elasticsearch in python/django

Tags: python, django, datatable, datatables

I've been trying this for 1 week now and I don't seem to get it to an end. What I am trying to do is populating a [datatable](http://datatables.net) from elasticsearch in a django application.

I have used [django_datatables_view](https://bitbucket.org/pigletto/django-datatables-view) to integrate datatables into my application and I've succeeded to populate a table with some data from an array which is JSON formatted (this is how data comes from elasticsearch)

Now, my question is: does anyone have a sample of code in which he extracted some data using elasticsearch ?

My code so far:

**mytable.html**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-offset-1">
                <table class="datatable table table-striped table-bordered hover" id="example" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {% for column in columns %}
                            <th>{{ column }}</th>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <script class="init">
                    $('#example').dataTable( {
                        "language": {
                            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Romanian.json"
                        },
                        searching: true,
                        ordering:  true,
                        "data": {{ dataforcolumns|safe }},
                        "columns": [
                            { "data": "Name" },
                            { "data": "Date" },
                            { "data": "Value" }
                        ],
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**views.py**

```
class TablePrettyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'mytable.html'

    def __init__(self, **args):
        self.args = args
        if 'interval' not in args:
            today = date.today()
            week = timedelta(days=6)
            args['interval'] = QueryInterval(today - week, today)

    def get_query(self):
        raise RuntimeError("You must implement the `get_query` method")

    def datapoint(self, key, row):
        if self.metric_name:
            value = row[self.metric_name]['value']
        else:
            value = row['doc_count']

        return key, value

    def datapoint(self, key, row):
        if self.metric_name:
            value = row[self.metric_name]['value']
        else:
            value = row['doc_count']

        return key, value

    def get_rows(self, res):
        def rows(obj, key_prefix, agg_name, *more_agg_names):
            for row in obj[agg_name]['buckets']:
                row_key = key_prefix + (row['key'],)
                if more_agg_names:
                    for yv in rows(row, row_key, *more_agg_names):
                        yield yv
                else:
                    yield self.datapoint(row_key, row)

        return rows(res['aggregations'], (), *self.agg_names)

    def html(self):
        query = self.get_query()
        res = try_cache(
            cache_key([self.index, query]),
            run_query, self.index, query,
        )

        rows = self.get_rows(res)
        series = self.get_series(rows)
        options = self.get_options(series)

        context = Context({
            'options': json.dumps(options),
        })

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        daterange = get_daterange(request.GET.get('daterange'))
        context = {}
        tablearray = [
            {'Name': 'Pope', 'day 1': '16 august 2015', 'day 7': '76436757'},
            {'Name': 'Alew', 'Date': '17 august 2015', 'Value': '76436757'},
        ]
        columns = ['Name', 'Date', 'Value']
        context['columns'] = columns
        context['dataforcolumns'] = json.dumps(tablearray)
        context['daterange'] = {'start': str(daterange[0]),
                                'end': str(daterange[1])}
        return render(request,
                      self.template_name,
                      context)
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no such implementation of elasticsearch and datatables out there. But it would be nice to have one

Comment: Sorry, not that familiar with ElasticSearch, but shouldn't you be able to just send a JSON object from ElasticSearch? Or even XML? If so, then DataTables should be able to handle it.

Comment: I am looking to do the same thing...there would have to be a middle man that would take the json response elasticsearch generates, and mapping it to a datatables type response format. Then some work around paging , its very possible

Comment: I was also looking for datatable migration from elastic search to Mongodb. Came accross below github which is informative.
https://github.com/datawrangl3r/mongoes